# show/hide images using buttons - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, button

I want to show/hide images with the click on a `<button>`

This is what i tried:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#buttontest').toggle(function() {
    $('#LogoTest').fadeOut('slow');
  }, function() {
    $('#LogoTest').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="buttontest" value="Show/Hide 1">
<a href="image1.jpg">
 <img src="image1.jpg" border="0" width="900" height="300" alt="image1" target="nowa_strona" id="LogoTest">
</a>
<br>
<input type="button" id="buttontest1" value="Show/Hide 2">
<a href="image2.jpg">
  <img src="image2.jpg" border="0" width="900" height="300" alt="image2" target="nowa_strona" id="LogoTest1">
</a>
<br>
```

How can i show/hide the images when i click on the corresponding `<button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best ways is wrap your button and image in a div element. Althrough in this case it's not necessary, but by this way you alway sure show/hide correct image. Just add a class name `logotest` in image, you can make it show/hide when click button with class `buttontest`.

Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/7xhxq/

Comment: what "it" are you mean? A image or a button?

Comment: Just use the function `toggle()`. The function `toggle("slow")` will show image if it hidding, and hide image if it's shown. See my example again!

Comment: Yes, but when site is loaded, we see button and below image, when i click on button image will hide, but i want to that when site is loaded, i will see only button, and image will show when i click on button, next click will hide image.

Comment: Insert `$('img.logotest').hide()` blow the `$(document).ready(function (){`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/7xhxq/1/

Answer (score 1):

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

> This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in
>   jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle()
>   that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the
>   event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#buttontest').on("click",function(e)
{  
 $('#LogoTest').toggle();
});

$('#buttontest1').on("click",function(e)
{  
 $('#LogoTest1').toggle();
});
```

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PgzrU/53/)

Hope It helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#buttontest').click(function() {
       $('#LogoTest').toggle('slow');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#YourButtonID').click(function() {
       $('#YourImageID').toggle('slow');
    }
 });
```

Please Note, the above code works superb. But I don't recommend it since jQuery’s `$(document).ready()` slows down. Here is the [document for your reference](http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/).

So, according to that you you should go with alternative for `$(document).ready()`.

For your question, you can do the alternative code something like:

```
$('#YourButtonID').on("click",function(e)
{  
 $('#YourImageID').toggle('slow');
});
```

Happy Exploring   :)